# How to create a multidimensional raster for a study area?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, landsat

I created a multidimensional raster for a whole set of Landsat 8 images, but I only want to use a specific study area from them. Is there any way to extract a multidimensional study area from a multidimensional raster? I am asking because it takes too long to do computations using the whole raster.

**Add Rasters To Mosaic Dataset** only works with Landsat 8 files/folders as an input, that have been downloaded and not modified using any **ArcGIS Pro Tools**. So, it doesn't let me insert the extracted study areas from my images. For instance, I extracted 10 study areas from each image using **Extract by Mask** but **Add Rasters To Mosaic Dataset** doesn't let me use them.

Comment: What do you mean by multidimensional? Do you mean your image has lots of bands, and you want to subset it to a specific study site and discard the rest of the image?

Comment: I mean that, I have created something which has all the bands from 10 different multispectral images from 2013 to 2022. With these I can use the multidimensional tab to search the year that I want. More info here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/an-overview-of-multidimensional-raster-data.htm

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't know it was a specific Arc function. Sorry im of little help here. My only suggestion would be, is there an option to clip a multidimensional image? That way you could just subset out the bit you wanted